# Spring Boot Test yml properties not being read in integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

In the following integration test, Spring Boot is unable to find the correct property file and read its values:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("embedded")
public class ApiApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    protected Environment env;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyProperty() {
        assertEquals("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb",
                env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    }
}
```

based on it selecting the property file application-embedded.yml:

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
    drop-first: true # should be false in prod but good for dev and test!
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: h2
    password: h2

security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3
  signing-key: MaYzkSjmkzPC57L
  security-realm: AvMaint Realm
  jwt:
    client-id: avmaintwebsitejwtclientid
    client-secret: XY7kmzoNzl100
    grant-type: password
    scope-read: read
    scope-write: write
    resource-ids: avmaintwebsitejwtresourceid
```

This test fails with: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required key 'url' not found". This is depite the application appearing to see the profile:

```
2018-05-20 10:42:36.810  INFO 66697 --- [    Test worker] au.com.avmaint.api.ApiApplicationTests   : The following profiles are active: embedded
```

It looks like, having found the profile, it just goes ahead and reads the 'default' values anyway.

anyone know why?

Also, I have found that by adding the annotation

`@TestPropertySource("/application-embedded.yml")`

I can force it to use the file, but what's the point of profiles then?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use @SpringBootTest(classes=YourMainApplicationClassName.class). Hope this will help to load your main class as the entry point and will also pick all related configurations by itself( i.e load the application context with all configurations)

Comment: thanks for looking at it, but this didn't work, again, it just loads the spring default properties. Also I thought that the point of `@SpringBootTest` was that it loaded everything as opposed to `@WebMvcTest`, is that not the case?